# What does A (EN) stands for on a battery?

Tags: batteries

I have seen many large car and trucks batteries where there example stands 200 Ah maraton battery 1200 A (EN). What does A (EN) mean?

Answer (score 2):

It probably refers to a test standard. Nominal capacity(A·h) by EN 60095-1 is rated at a fixed discharge current of I/20, within 20 hours until final discharge voltage of 10.5 V at 25 °C is reached.

Comment: How did you find this information?

Comment: Just a guess as to where to start looking - I'm an electronics engineer